# The labels in the plot don't appear

Tags: plotting, interpolation, labeling

the labels in the plot doesn't appear, axeslabel, plotlabel and plotlabels.

```
data = {{2200, 5}, {1700, 10}, {1050, 20}, {640, 50}, {420, 100}};
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {rpm^3, rpm^2, rpm}, rpm];

data1 = {{600, 5}, {800, 10}, {400, 20}, {640, 50}, {440, 100}};
  lm1 = LinearModelFit[data1, {rpm^3, rpm^2, rpm}, rpm];

Show[ListPlot[{data, data1}, Filling -> Bottom], 
 ListLinePlot[{data, data1}], 
 Plot[lm[rpm], {rpm, 0, 125}, PlotLabel -> {"Natural"}, 
  AxesLabel -> {rpm, \[Mu]}, PlotLabels -> {"A6", "A7"}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are aiming for?

```
Show[
 ListPlot[{data, data1}, Filling -> Bottom, PlotLabels -> {"A6", "A7"}]
 , ListLinePlot[{data, data1}]
 , Plot[lm[rpm], {rpm, 0, 125}]
 , PlotLabel -> "Natural"
 , AxesLabel -> {"rpm", "\[Mu]"}
 ]
```

> [image]